# How to denoise AOVs and export multiEXR

Tags: compositing-nodes

Any thoughts on how to render/output denoised AOVs within a multiEXR for compositing outside Blender (Davinci Resolve or AE)?

When I denoise my renders in Blender compositing, I’ve no idea how to export the denoised result as a multiEXR.

Btw: found a possible solution in the forums but the end result is still with noisy AOVs.

Thanks in advance! (Blender noob here)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Denoise node to denoise anything, and then use a File Output node to combine the denoised passes into an EXR Multilayer

[image: demo nodes]